# Modem Advan Jetz DT-08 Tanpa Terminal

Tags: gui, usb-modem

Mas, mau tanya nih. Gimana ya caranya koneksi modem Advan DT-08 yang tidak pake terminal?
Masalahnya ada temen ane yang punya dan cenderung tidak menyukai terminal (GUI method preferred).
Thanks atas perhatian dan bantuan Mas...

Answer (score 0):

Sebelumnya, kenapa gak pake bahasa inggris. Ini kan forum internasional.

Apakah modem tersebut sudah dikenali ubuntu, dan bisa digunakan koneksi? Jika ya, maka cukup membuat profil koneksi dari Network Manager Applet.

Gambar: [Network Manager Applet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GRc8.png)

Jika belum ada drivernya, silakan baca [tulisan ini](http://yusuva.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/menggunakan-modem-usb-3g-advan-dt-8-di-ubuntu-linux/) dulu. Terpaksa harus pakai konsol